# How to bind child array in array by using Knockout.js?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout to bind data to a table:

I have `obj`:

```
obj=[{id:"1",productName:"laptop",tag:[promotion,blackfriday]},{id:"2",productName:"Samsung galaxy note III",tag:[samsung,galaxy]}]
```

**HTML:**

```
<table data-bind="foreach:list" id="listProduct">
  <tr>
      <td data-bind="text:productName"></td>
      <td data-bind="foreach:obj.tag">
          <p data-bind="text:tag"></p>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript** (to bind data):

```
ko.applyBindings({ list: obj }, document.getElementById('listProduct'));
```

But it only displays the product name and does not bind "tag" obj; I want Knockout to bind data as:

```
    Product Name                        Tag
1   Laptop                              promotion
                                        blackfriday

2   Samsung galaxy note III             samsung
                                        galaxy
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the code you gave, there are a couple simple things that will fix this for you:

1. `productName` is misspelled
2. the `foreach:obj.tag` should be `foreach:tag`
3. the `text:tag` should be `text:$data` (see [the docs on this](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html))
4. your tags in the data given are not strings - so it won't work if they aren't defined elsewhere

JS:

```
var obj = [{
    id: "1",
    productName: "laptop",
    tag: ["promotion", "blackfriday"]
}, {
    id: "2",
    productName: "Samsung galaxy note III",
    tag: ["samsung", "galaxy"]
}];

ko.applyBindings({ list: obj }, document.getElementById('listProduct'));
```

HTML:

```
<table  id="listProduct">
  <tr data-bind="foreach:list">
    <td data-bind="text:productName">test</td>
    <td data-bind="foreach:tag">
      <p data-bind="text:$data">test</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The implementation that are you using is too odd, and I think is not correct. For example I don't know why are you retrieving the `listProduct` element and sending as argument to `ko.applyBidning`, this is not how knockout works.
2. You also have mistakes using inside object in the foreach binding, check out [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) to see the correct usage. Even you have a misspelled in the HTML with the `productName` value.
3. You have syntax errors inside both `tag` arrays, the values are string so you need to add quotes to each element.

I will show a better and clean way to do it fixing the issues mentioned above:

**JS**

```
function VM(){ //declare your VM constructor.
  this.list = ko.observableArray([
      {id: '1', productName: 'laptop', tag: ['promotion', 'blackfriday']},
      {id: '2', productName: 'Samsung galaxy note III', tag: ['samsung', 'galaxy']}
    ]); //Add and observable array an set your data. If you don't need that this array be an observable just use a normal JS array.
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM()); //apply binding
```

**HTML**

```
<table data-bind="foreach: list">
<tr>
    <td data-bind="text: productName"></td>
    <td data-bind="foreach: tag">
      <p data-bind="text: $data"></p>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ianaya89/ceLpno3e/) to see it working.